# Watching Solidity event gives error: TypeError: watch is not a function

Tags: solidity, truffle, react

I am trying to watch a Solidity event in my React app, but I keep getting the following exception error thrown:

`TypeError: MyEvent.watch is not a function`

I am sure the event is present in `MyContract.json`. Here is what my code looks like:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      // Get network provider and web3 instance.
      const web3 = await getWeb3();

      // Get the contract instance.
      const Contract = truffleContract(MyContract);
      Contract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
      const contractInstance = await Contract.deployed();

      // Watch for MyEvent
      contractInstance.MyEvent().watch((error, result) => {});


    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);  // always gives: TypeError: contractInstance.MyEvent(...).watch is not a function
    }
  };
```

And this is how MyContract.sol code looks like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract MyContract {
    event MyEvent();

    function myFunction() public {
        emit MyEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the solidity code where you define the event?

Comment: I would perform a sanity check and `console.log(contractInstance)` to see if it looks correct for the contract you are importing. Share details here too :)

Comment: If you happen to be using Web3 1.x beta, then the methods have changed. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it! Now however I get the following error instead: `Contract.events.MyEvent is not a function`

Comment: The issue now seems to be that `truffle-contract` does not support Web3 1.x beta, hence it's not returning a compatible contract object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `myContract.MyEvent.watch` has been changed in [Web3 v1](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events). It is now `myContract.events.MyEvent`

But, event Listing in Web3 v1.x require websokets to be enabled on the connected node. And, Ganache version 6 and bellow does not support websockets. However, websockets is available at version 7; but it is now in alpha version.

So, you can try with [Ganache 7](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/releases/tag/v7.0.0-beta.0). You can also use latest Geth version in developer mode. Or you may explore [Drizzle](https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle) as it is handly in syncing with the blockchain state and this includs events...

References:

- [Web3 v1 - Contract Events](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events)
- [Enable WebSocket support of Ganache CLI and Subscribe to Events](https://hanezu.github.io/posts/Enable-WebSocket-support-of-Ganache-CLI-and-Subscribe-to-Events.html)
- [Ganache cli v7: Candy Apple  - Beta 0](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/releases/tag/v7.0.0-beta.0)

Comment: can we link ganache-cli v7 with [ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache)